# twitter bootstrap thumbnail alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I have an issue with aligning thumbnails in a Twitter Bootstrap well:

1. I'm using fluid layout
2. My thumbnails are 183 by 154 px
3. I would like to use fixed image sizes, but variable margins and that the thumbnails perfectly align within the area they are in.

**This is the result for what I have so far:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qUA6.png

As you may notice; the images are aligned to much to the left.
The thumbnails are wrapped as such:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span6">
```

My html:

```
  <ul id="nwthumbs">
     <li><a href="#" ><img src="Fernando-Alonso-Ferrari-3_2799133.jpg"><h2><span>Fernando Alonso has credited Ferrari's decision to stop for a new set of we...</span></h2></a>
      <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" >Read More</button></li>
      <li><a href="#" ><img src="Sir-Alex-Ferguson_2794602.jpg">
          <h2><span data-bind="html: titleShortened">Sir Alex Ferguson says there is 'no chance' of Manchester United repeating ...</span></h2></a><button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" >Read More</button></li><li><a href="#" ><img src="Paul-Bohan-2012_2799199.jpg">
 <h2><span>Local Hero claimed a first victory of the year with a determined effort in ...</span>
      </h2> </a><button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" >
                                        Read More</button>
                                </li>
              <li><a href="#" ><img src="Douglas_2675905.jpg">
      <h2><span>FC Twente chairman Joop Munsterman admits he is unsure whether Newcastle Un...</span></h2> </a><button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" >
                                        Read More</button>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" >
                  <img src="Darryl-Westlake-Walsall_2465450.jpg">
                                    <h2>
      <span>Sheffield United have confirmed the signing of promising defender Darryl We...</span>
                                    </h2>
                                </a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" >
                                        Read More</button>
                                </li>
   </ul>
```

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

What I have tried so far is making the pictures variable size; width 100% and height 100%, that works, but when resizing to a smaller ViewPort, it will resize the images instead of wrapping the images so that they appear in two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this CSS :

```
#nwthumbs {
  text-align:center;
}

#nwthumbs > li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    float: none; /* this is the part that makes it work */
}
```

Comment: Wow..Im impressed, that was it!!

Comment: I had the same problem a week or two and found this answer on the web. I don't remember where though. Anyway, happy I helped you! :)